# MaskFormatter makes Components Sporadically Appear In Panel

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, jformattedtextfield, maskformatter

I'm trying to make the GUI for a program that solved quadratic equations.

I'm using `JFormattedTextfields` to restrict user entry to numbers, and to do this I'm using `MaskFormatter`. Problem is, this causes the components to fluctuate between appearing correctly in the panel, partly appearing, and then not appearing at all.

I've figured out that the problem has something to do with `MaskFormatter`, because when I call the constructor that takes no arguments for `JFormattedTextFields`, everything appears correctly.

This is my code:

```
public JPanel createEquationPanel(int w, int h) throws ParseException {
    equationPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    equationPanel.setSize(w,h);
    equationPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Quadratic Equation"));
    equationPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    aLabel = createLabel("a =", "Enter the \'a\' value for the equation", Font.ITALIC, 25.0f);
    bLabel = createLabel("b =", "Enter the \'b\' value for the equation", Font.ITALIC, 25.0f);
    cLabel = createLabel("c =", "Enter the \'c\' value for the equation", Font.ITALIC, 25.0f);
    equation = createLabel("", "The equation", Font.PLAIN, 35.0f);

    a = createFormattedTextField();
    b = createFormattedTextField();
    c = createFormattedTextField();

    equationPanel.add(aLabel,setGbc(0,0,0.1,0.1));
    equationPanel.add(a,setGbc(1,0,0.1,0.1));
    equationPanel.add(bLabel,setGbc(2,0,0.1,0.1));
    equationPanel.add(b,setGbc(3,0,0.1,0.1));
    equationPanel.add(cLabel,setGbc(4,0,0.1,0.1));
    equationPanel.add(c,setGbc(5,0,0.1,0.1));

    equationPanel.add(equation,    setGbc(2,2,GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START,5,0.3,0.3));

    return equationPanel;
}
```

Method that creates the `FormattedTextFields`

```
private JFormattedTextField createFormattedTextField() {
    JFormattedTextField tf = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("######"));
    tf.setColumns(5);

    return tf;
} 

private MaskFormatter createFormatter(String s) {
    MaskFormatter mask = null;

    try {
        mask = new MaskFormatter(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error occurred", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    return mask;
}
```

Also, I specify a size for the panel (w:495,h:250), and I noticed that even if the `JLabels` and `JFormattedTextfields` don't appear initially, when I resize the actual frame they *do* appear. So in short, they are always there, they just don't always appear in the panel size I specify.

Comment: Correct output: http://imgur.com/7R5UOzG
Incorrect outputs: http://imgur.com/1XQMckc, http://imgur.com/1XQMckc

Comment: you have a lot of undefined variables set in `createEquationPanel` (`equationPanel`, `aLabel`, etc.).  Where are they declared?

Comment: They are declared in the class outside of the method:

    private JPanel equationPanel;
 private JFormattedTextField a,b,c;
 private JLabel aLabel, bLabel, cLabel;
 private JLabel equation = new JLabel("");
 
 GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();